# How to solve the problem of not being informed of successful payments by the 3rd party system used by my website?

Tags: e-commerce, web-applications, payment-processing

I have a subscription based website that interacts with a 3rd party system to handle the payments.  The steps to process a new subscriber registration are as follow:

1. The subscriber enters his/her details in the subscription form and click on the submit button.
2. Assuming the details specified are valid, a new record is created in the database to store these details.
3. The subscriber is then redirected to the website of the 3rd party system (similar to paypal) to process the payment.
4. Once the payment is succesful, the 3rd party website then redirect the subscriber back to our website.
5. At this time, I know that the payment was succesful, so the record in the database is updated to indicate that payment has been made successfully.

A problem that I have found occurring quite often is that if a subscriber pays but does not complete the process correctly (e.g. uses the back browser, closes the window), his/her record in the database doesn't get updated about this.  Accordingly, I don't know if s/he has paid by just looking the record and need to wait for the report from the 3rd party system to find this out.

How do you solve this problem?

PS. One of the main reasons to store their details into the database before the payment process is done is so they can come back to complete the payment without re-entering their details again.  For example, when their credit cards were rejected by the 3rd party system and they need to sort this out with their financial institution which may take a while.

Comment: +1 we have the same problem. I don't think there's a solvation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third-party payment system should inform you of the successful transaction regardless of what the user does.

For example, in PayPal, an IPN (instant payment notification) is sent to your server as POST data to a URL that you specify. Your server then verifies with Paypal that the transaction is genuine, and if so, updates the database record to indicate the subscription is valid. At a point in the future, PayPal may *or may not* then redirect the user back to your website. (The "may not" can occur in cases such as the user closing their browser, hitting Back, or jumping to a new URL)

Note that this "conversation" between Paypal and your server is independent of the user's session - it is a "private conversation" between you and PayPal about that user's transaction.

Obviously there can be communications outages and server failures, so if Paypal does not get the validation request from your server immediately it will periodically send retries to your server to ensure that the transaction is eventually completed.

If your payment system doesn't have at least some basic mechanism for ensuring transaction reliability, then choose a different provider. Chances are that they do, but you will have to implement things correctly on your server to be sure that the system works properly.

P.S. It is quite normal to require a user to log in (and thus be registered in the database) before they initiate any financial transaction. You need to gather all the relevant information before they go to purchase, as after the purchase you have no way of guaranteeing that they will return to you to provide any further information.